# Laravel get products in the same category

Tags: laravel, controller, eloquent, many-to-many

Hi im trying to pass all the products in the same category to a view
my products table has cat_id which related to cat_id in the categories table,
i got all the data from a product id to a single product view and i want to show related products to that product too
here my passing to product page's controller

```
public function product($id){
        $product = Products::where('pro_id',$id)->Paginate(1);
        $products=Products::where('cat_id',$product->cat_id)->get();
        return view('front.product.product', compact('product','products'));
    }
```

the $product variable works
but not the $products variable
i get the following error when try to uses $products variable

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$cat_id
```

and my variables when trying to pass to view

```
@foreach($product as $show)
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="col-md-5 grid">
        <div class="thumb-image"> <img src="{!! url('public/backend/images/products/'.$show->pro_img) !!}" data-imagezoom="true" class="img-responsive" style="width: 305px; height: 400px;"> </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-7 single-top-in">
                        <div class="single-para simpleCart_shelfItem">
                            <h1>{{$show->pro_title}}</h1>
                            <p>{{$show->pro_descript}}</p>

                                <label  class="add-to item_price">{{$show->pro_price}}</label>

                            <div class="available">
                                <h6>Description</h6>
                                <h4>{{$show->pro_detail}}</h4>
                        </div>
                                <a href="#" class="cart item_add">Add to cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            <div class="content-top1">
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
            @foreach($products as $related)
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-md3">
                                <div class="col-md1 simpleCart_shelfItem">
                                    <a href="single.html">
                                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{!! url('public/backend/images/products/'.$related->pro_img) !!}" alt="" />
                                    </a>
                                    <h3><a href="single.html">{{$related->pro_detail}}</a></h3>
                                    <div class="price">
                                            <h5 class="item_price">{{$related->pro_price}}</h5>
                                            <a href="#" class="item_add">Add To Cart</a>
                                            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
            @endforeach
</div>
@endforeach
```

when i dd($product) with paginate(1)

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#237 ▼
  #total: 1
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Collection {#226 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      0 => Products {#232 ▼
        #table: "tbl_products"
        #primaryKey: "pro_id"
        +timestamp: false
        #filltable: array:9 [▼
          0 => "cat_id"
          1 => "pro_title"
          2 => "pro_descript"
          3 => "pro_detail"
          4 => "pro_img"
          5 => "quantity"
          6 => "pro_date"
          7 => "pro_price"
          8 => "pro_status"
        ]
        #connection: "mysql"
        #keyType: "int"
        +incrementing: true
        #with: []
        #withCount: []
        #perPage: 15
        +exists: true
        +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        #attributes: array:12 [▼
          "pro_id" => 2
          "cat_id" => 9
          "pro_title" => "veston "
          "pro_descript" => "look good"
          "pro_detail" => "blue jean"
          "pro_img" => "1516593265.jpg"
          "quantity" => 8
          "pro_date" => "2018-01-22 10:54:25"
          "pro_price" => 400.0
          "pro_status" => 0
          "created_at" => "2018-01-22 03:54:25"
          "updated_at" => "2018-01-22 03:54:25"
        ]
        #original: array:12 [▼
          "pro_id" => 2
          "cat_id" => 9
          "pro_title" => "veston "
          "pro_descript" => "look good"
          "pro_detail" => "blue jean"
          "pro_img" => "1516593265.jpg"
          "quantity" => 8
          "pro_date" => "2018-01-22 10:54:25"
          "pro_price" => 400.0
          "pro_status" => 0
          "created_at" => "2018-01-22 03:54:25"
          "updated_at" => "2018-01-22 03:54:25"
        ]
        #changes: []
        #casts: []
        #dates: []
        #dateFormat: null
        #appends: []
        #dispatchesEvents: []
        #observables: []
        #relations: []
        #touches: []
        +timestamps: true
        #hidden: []
        #visible: []
        #fillable: []
        #guarded: array:1 [▼
          0 => "*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  #perPage: 1
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://localhost:81/shop/product/2"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is accessing these variables in your view?

Comment: i edited it with the view

Comment: `$product = Products::where('pro_id',$id)->Paginate(1)[0];`

Comment: it still give the same error as when using  the ->first() method on $product : Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 2):

```
$product = Products::where('pro_id',$id)->Paginate(1);
```

this code returns array
cahnge code to like below:

```
$product = Products::where('pro_id',$id)->first();
```

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object (View: product\product.blade.php)

Comment: now it show all the output datas of product are error , when i used paginate(1) it worked and pass out the data on view without error

Comment: @o0o0keem if `$product` is `null` it means there is no a product with `pro_od = $id` in the table.

Comment: i used the $id to get the product view match the pro_id of the product that user click on

Comment: here my href to the product page {{route('front.product.show', ['id' => $recent->pro_id]) }} the href is on the main page

Comment: please `dd($products);` and get your result

Comment: `@foreach($products as $related)`  you not determine `$products `

Comment: really ? but i though i determined it in the controller when i compact('products') and pass it to view

Answer (score 0):

Here you are calling a paginator:

`$product = Products::where('pro_id',$id)->Paginate(1);`

Try this instead:

`$product = Products::where('pro_id',$id)->first();`

-or-

`$product = Products::where('pro_id',$id)->paginate(1)[0];`

-or finally-

`$product = Product::findOrFail($id);`

The latter would only work if you've set `protected $primaryKey = 'pro_id';` within your class.

The details:

When you called `$product = Products::where('pro_id',$id)->Paginate(1);' you are getting a`Paginator`instance back from the data layer. The`Paginator`doesn't have the properties that a`Product` does in your example, which is where the error is coming from.

A paginator is a different type of collection, but it is a type of collection, also. Think about it like an array or like a Java style `ArrayList` which is a complex wrapper class for an array that provides additional funcitonality. A paginator is similar, but with an extra level of abstraction to provide view based pagination. You can access objects on the 'page' within the paginator similarly to how you can get array-like access to objects in a collection.

If you just return a collection, then doing

`$product = Products::where('pro_id',$id)->get();`

Gives you the the matching id as a collection. In order to actually see the object you want you would need to do this:

`$product = Products::where('pro_id',$id)->paginate(1)[0];`

to get the first item in that collection.